# While loops in Python 3 syntax, while L and L.data != key

Tags: python

I have this function for linked lists in Python3:

```
    def search_list(L: ListNode, key: int) -> ListNode:
       while L and L.val != key:
          L = L.next
       return L
```

So my question is what is the difference between the above and:

```
    def search_list(L: ListNode, key: int) -> ListNode:
       while L != None and L.val != key:
          L = L.next
       return L
```

Is there a difference?

Is the first way of writing it is just saying: *"while L is not NULL/None and L.val does not equal key, keep the loop running?"*

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`if L:` checks if `L` is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/11556864).
`if L != None` checks if `L` is not `None`.

The biggest difference would be when `L` is `False`.
The former won't execute because it is `if False`.
The latter will execute because `False != None` is true.

In your use case it won't make any difference.
But be aware of how "truthy" and "falsy" values work in if/while expressions because they do make big difference in certain cases.

Comment: I'll just add that the Pythonic way to check against `None` or any other singleton is `if L is not None:` instead of `if L != None:`.   This is because the = and != operators can be overloaded but the `is` operator can not.

Comment: Using `is not None` is particularly important with NumPy arrays, where trying to use `if arr` or `if arr != None` will usually give a TypeError due to how NumPy arrays handle `__ne__` and `__bool__`.